# Обновить clang ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, clion, clang, c++20

У меня clang 10, а очень хочетя include ranges. Вроде как такое можно только с clang 13. Надо как-то обновить, но как - понять не смогла. Очень прошу помощи.

Пользуюсь clion и и обновила gcc до gcc-11, в котором необходимая библиотека есть. Однако clion, оставаясь при этом комфортной ide, настроен использовать clang. Как начать пользоваться им с gcc, в чем я при этом выиграю и потеряю, более ли это трудоемкое мероприятие, нежели обновление clang - я совершенно не понимаю.

Кроме того, возможно, можно подключить ranges как external library, но как это сделать и где ее взять - тоже непонятно.

у меня ubuntu 20.04...

попробовала так сделать, поменяла еще в нескольких местах на gcc-11, кэш файл больно большой, но  измененная мной часть выглядит так
~

```
//Path to a program.
CMAKE_ADDR2LINE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/addr2line

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ar

//Choose the type of build, options are: None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo
// MinSizeRel ...
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug

//Id string of the compiler for the CodeBlocks IDE. Automatically
// detected when left empty
CMAKE_CODEBLOCKS_COMPILER_ID:STRING=

//The CodeBlocks executable
CMAKE_CODEBLOCKS_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=CMAKE_CODEBLOCKS_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND

//Additional command line arguments when CodeBlocks invokes make.
// Enter e.g. -j<some_number> to get parallel builds
CMAKE_CODEBLOCKS_MAKE_ARGUMENTS:STRING=-j8

//Enable/Disable color output during build.
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON

//CXX compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/c++

//A wrapper around 'ar' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ar-11

//A wrapper around 'ranlib' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-11

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG

//C compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/cc

//A wrapper around 'ar' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ar-11

//A wrapper around 'ranlib' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-11

//Flags used by the C compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=
```

Это даже запускаетя, однако подключить ranges все еще невозможно... возможно, здесь надо было что-то изменить [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могу проверить точно, но попробуйте так: 1) Установите clang-13 командой в терминале `sudo apt install clang-13`. 2) После установки также в терминале выполните команду `which clang-13`. Это покажет путь к компилятору. 3) В CLion перейдите на вкладку "Кэш" в окне инструмента CMake и установите путь компилятора (тот, который вернула команда из пункта 2) к переменной CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER. Затем нажмите "Enter" и нажмите кнопку "Применить изменения" и "Обновить".

Comment: sudo apt install clang-13 не помогает - выдает E: Unable to locate package clang-13

Comment: Точно. Его нет в репозитории. Можете попробовать провернуть это с новым gcc. Выполните пункт 2 для  gcc-11. Ну и пункт 3 тоже.

Comment: попробовала, компилируется, но ranges не подключается все равно (

Comment: Новый кланг ставится командой [`bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"`](https://apt.llvm.org/).

Comment: Кеш cmake руками явно не надо менять... *"возможно, здесь надо было что-то изменить"* Ну, попробуйте после установки кланга поставить "C compiler" = `clang-13`, "C++ compiler" = `clang++-13`.

Comment: если обновить до последней убунты, то и clang13 будет.

Answer (score 0):

по итогу мне помогло прописать это в настройках clion, в кэш файле изменения на gcc-11 jcnfdbkf[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]